# Spring Security Sequence of execution

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I am not able to find out where and when exactly the authentication manager is executed by spring security. I mean there are certian filters which are executed sequentially as below:

```
  FIRST
- CHANNEL_FILTER
- CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER
- SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER
- LOGOUT_FILTER
- X509_FILTER

- PRE_AUTH_FILTER
- CAS_FILTER
- FORM_LOGIN_FILTER
- OPENID_FILTER
- BASIC_AUTH_FILTER
- SERVLET_API_SUPPORT_FILTER
- REMEMBER_ME_FILTER
- ANONYMOUS_FILTER

- EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER
- SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER
- FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR
- SWITCH_USER_FILTER
- LAST
```

But when exactly authentication provider authenticates the provided username and password, i mean to ask after which these below filters is the authentication provider is executed .

Regards
Jayendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Spring Security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html):

> The order that filters are defined in the chain is very important.
>   Irrespective of which filters you are actually using, the order should
>   be as follows:
>
> 1. `ChannelProcessingFilter`, because it might need to redirect to a different protocol
> 2. `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`, so a SecurityContext can be set up in the SecurityContextHolder at the beginning of a web request, and
>      any changes to the SecurityContext can be copied to the HttpSession
>      when the web request ends (ready for use with the next web request)
> 3. `ConcurrentSessionFilter`, because it uses the SecurityContextHolder functionality but needs to update the SessionRegistry to reflect
>      ongoing requests from the principal
> 4. **Authentication processing mechanisms - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter,
>      BasicAuthenticationFilter etc - so that the SecurityContextHolder can
>      be modified to contain a valid Authentication request token**
> 5. `The SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter`, if you are using it to install a Spring Security aware HttpServletRequestWrapper into your
>      servlet container
> 6. `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter`, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      and the request presents a cookie that enables remember-me services to
>      take place, a suitable remembered Authentication object will be put
>      there
> 7. `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`, so that if no earlier authentication processing mechanism updated the SecurityContextHolder,
>      an anonymous Authentication object will be put there
> 8. `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, to catch any Spring Security exceptions so that either an HTTP error response can be returned or an
>      appropriate AuthenticationEntryPoint can be launched
> 9. `FilterSecurityInterceptor`, to protect web URIs and raise exceptions when access is denied

So the authentication manager is called at step 4. If you look at the source code of [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) you will see something like:

```
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    // ...
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}
```

Comment: very true . realized this while implementing a custom usernamepasswordauthentication filter which requires injection of authentication manager .