# When SecurityContextHolder.setContext() is invoked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a trouble with `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` which is null. I have tried a lot of combination with annotations and examples. (code from site does not work in my application, do not know why yet).

So for now I get `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`. If you look at [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.java) you spot that `getAuthentification` is delegated to `SecurityContextHolderStrategy` which thread local field and populated during `SecurityContextHolder` initialization. Anybody know when spring security should "populate" it with authentification? (in servlet filter, before method invocation, etc.)

**UPDATED**

Security configuration is:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.EnableGlobalAuthentication;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```

RestController

```
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SecurityChecker {

  @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
  @RequestMapping("/allow")
  public String allow() {
    return "{\"status\" : \"ok\"}";
  }

  @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
  @RequestMapping("/anonymous")
  public String anonymous() {
    return "{\"status\" : \"anonymous\"}";
  }
}
```

Application initializer

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{AppConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{SecurityConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/rest/*"};
}
```

`AppConfiguration` contains some code for data source, entityManager and transactionManager config for sprng data rest.

Request to `/rest/allow` url result in exception `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

**Note**

Form authorization config may be not correct, I tried to replace it with basic auth, but anyway I should get unauthorized response instead fo exception.

**Versions**

Spring is `4.0.5.RELEASE`, spring security is `4.0.2.RELEASE`.

Comment: Take a look at the sequence of steps in the security filter chain: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32679802/1291150 ... The authentication is being added to the context in authentication filters. For instance in `BasicAuthenticationFilter` when you use basic auth. ([Code on Github here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L184)).

Comment: So to make authentification object populated, I need to add one of these servlet filter, right?

Comment: These filters should be added automatically when you configure Spring Security. It's hard to say without seeing your project, but let's say you have basic authentication enabled in Spring Security configuration and set that `/secured/*` requires authenticated users. Spring Security should then make sure that anyone accessing that URL will have to be authenticated (requuest will go through the filter chain and the basic auth filter) and the authentication will be set automatically if correct password and username is entered.

Comment: Maybe share your Spring Security config/project structure or other relevant details which might help solve this, if possible.

Comment: Thank, for your interest. :) Updated the question.

Comment: The problem seems obvious. By using this `.antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll()` you are telling Spring Security "all users, authenticated or not can access URLs matching this pattern". But your controller performs some authorization checks (`isAuthenticated()`). Maybe you want to add rule like `.antMatchers("/rest/allow").authenticated()` before the `rest/**` rule? If you do that you can also remove the `PreAuthorize` annotations on controller, because the access will already be controlled by those rules. Also form login is probably not the best option for REST api.

Comment: I removed `@PreAuthorise` and change security config to `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/allow").authenticated().and().formLogin();` I can now access `rest/allow`, but not because fix problem, but because security is disabled for that url. When I put a breake point to `return "{\"status\" : \"ok\"}";` line and add `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to watches, it show me `null`. :( May be my config wrong? Could you please provide config for deny unauthorization access?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90811/discussion-between-bohuslav-burghardt-and-cherry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for fixing spring security was very simple just add:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

and move `SecurityConfiguration.class` to `getRootConfigClasses()` method.

And everything works! :)

Comment: Could you provide more information about where you added the code and what other changes were necessary. I have the same problem. Thank you.